# Why it shows AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_variable' while I did not use tf.get_variable？

Tags: python, model, tensorflow2.0

When I tried to execute the code:

```
# Build template graph.
with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope(self.scope, reuse=tf.compat.v1.AUTO_REUSE):
    assert tf.compat.v1.get_variable_scope().name == self.scope
    with absolute_name_scope(self.scope): # ignore surrounding name_scope
        with tf.control_dependencies(None): # ignore surrounding control_dependencies
            tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
            self.input_templates = [tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, name=name) for name in self.input_names]
            out_expr = self._build_func(*self.input_templates, is_template_graph=True, **self.static_kwargs)
```

It reports the error as below:

```
 File "models/pggan_tf_official/tfutil.py", line 478, in _init_graph
    out_expr = self._build_func(*self.input_templates, is_template_graph=True, **self.static_kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 175, in G_paper
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_variable'
```

I got very confused about it since I didnt used get_variable function in line 478 (i.e. last line).
So may I know how to solve this?

I tried to delete "tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()" but there will be another error "RuntimeError: tf.placeholder() is not compatible with eager execution."

Comment: Which tensorflow are you using? As I can see most of these apis were compatible with `TF 1.x`, but these apis are replaced with some new Apis in `TF 2.x` like -  `tf.placeholder()` is replaced with `tf.keras.Input()` and can use `tf.Variable()` in place of `tf.get_variable()`. Please check this [migration guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) for your reference.